# Which part of the CAP Theorem does CRDT Sacrifice?

Tags: system, distribute, crdt

CRDT or Conflict-Free Replicated Data Type follows a strong eventual consistency guarantee, essentially meaning consistency is guaranteed to be achieved at some point in time in the future.

My question is, is the Consistency part of the CAP theorem sacrificed or else which one is?

Answer (score 3):

CRDTs sacrifice consistency to achieve availability at least in the most straightforward utilization of them that does nothing to check that you have received inputs from all potential clients (nodes in the network).

However CRDT is a kind of data structure and is not a distributed algorithm so its behavior in a distributed environment will depend on the full distributed algorithm that they participated in.

Some similar ideas are discussed in https://blog.acolyer.org/2017/08/17/on-the-design-of-distributed-programming-models/:

> Lasp is an example of an AP model that sacrifices consistency for availability. In Lasp, all data structures are CRDTs...